# $P(|X_1+X_2|<x)\le P(|X_1|<x)$ for every independent centered continuous $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be zero mean independent continuous random variables. Then, is it true that $P(|X_1+X_2|<x)\le P(|X_1|<x)$.

The intuition is that summing independent variables increase variance, and would make them farther from zero more likely.

Comment: The result does not hold: consider $(X_1,X_2)$ uniform on $\{-1,1\}^2$ then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and centered, $P(|X_1+X_2|<1)=P(X_2=-X_1)=\frac12$ and $P(|X_1|<1)=0$.

Comment: ok, let us assume a continuous distribution rather than discrete. Does the result hold for continuous distribution? I am changing the question to add "continuous"

Comment: Then consider $(X_1,X_2)$ uniform on $U\times U$ with $U=(-1-u,-1+u)\cup(1-u,1+u)$ for some small $u$. (Changing the question once you received some comments or answers is not recommended, for obvious reasons.)

Comment: All: this question is solved by Did (many thanks to Did). I have modified it to account for this counterexample in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765545/px-1x-2x-le-px-1x-for-every-independent-centered-x-1-and-x-2-wi .  Did: If you would like to get points for correct answer, please put your answer above in answers and I can select that. Thanks.