# $P(|X_1+X_2|<x)\le P(|X_1|<x)$ for every independent centered $X_1$ and $X_2$ with decreasing pdf?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be zero mean independent continuous random variables. Let the density function of both random variables be symmetric around origin, and $f_{X_i}(t)$ is monotonically decreasing with $t$ for $t>0$. Then, is it true that $P(|X_1+X_2|<x)\le P(|X_1|<x)$.

The intuition is that summing independent variables increase variance, and would make them farther from zero more likely. We already see in the question I asked before ([$P(|X_1+X_2|<x)\le P(|X_1|<x)$ for every independent centered continuous $X_1$ and $X_2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765075/px-1x-2x-le-px-1x-for-every-independent-centered-continuous-x-1-a)) that this does not hold in general - but this holds if the distribution were Gaussian. Can we generalize the statement to the case above?

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765075/px-1x-2x-le-px-1x-for-every-independent-centered-continuous-x-1-a

Comment: Yes. Since that was disproved, this adds more conditions to the problem. It  will be bad to change that question, since that was answered. I have linked it.

Comment: With your edit you show your effort and everything is fine.

Comment: Assuming that the PDF of $X_1$ is radially decreasing, one can show that $P(|X_1+y|<x)\leqslant P(|X_1|<x)$ for every $y$, hence, as soon as $X_2$ is independent of $X_1$ and with no hypothesis on the distribution of $X_2$, indeed $P(|X_1+X_2|<x)\leqslant P(|X_1|<x)$.